# Launch docker deamon at startup when offline

Tags: docker, init, init.d

On a 14.04 LTS, my docker daemon doesn't start at init when internet isn't available. An `ifconfig` doesn't show any `docker0`. The only related message I've found is in `/var/log/kern.log` :

```
IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): docker0: link is not ready
```

I can start the daemon manually:

```
sudo service docker start
```

But how to go around launching the docker daemon at startup when offline?

Update: docker daemon is already started at init

```
$ ls /etc/init.d/docker
/etc/init.d/docker
```

but it doesn't start when the init is offline. I haven't found any check related to network in `/etc/init.d/docker`

Comment: Add `service docker start` to `/etc/rc.local` and enable rc.local service: `sudo update-rc.d rc.local enable`. otherwise you should edit the docker's init script I guess...

Comment: @Ravexina: my docker daemon is already started at init and it works when internet is available but it doesn't start when the init is offline. I haven't found any check related to network in `/etc/init.d/docker`.  I've updated the question.